# Using encrypted fields in SOSL query gives in 0 results

Tags: apex, sosl, encryption, text

My org has Classic encryption and I have a encrypted field in contact object.
I am trying to use that field in SOSL.

```
FIND {123456789} IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING CONTACT(NAME)
```

This is returning 0 results even though I have populated this field as `123456789` in one of the contact records.

Comment: what type of field is it?

Comment: This is a text(Encrypted) field and Mask Type as Social Security Number.I am able to see the value in record page as I have view encrypted data permission

Comment: consider accepting the answer below if it helped answer your question. Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your field is a custom encrypted field,
SOSL only supports the following:

> All custom fields of type text, text area, long text area, rich text
> area, email, and phone

You can check the [searchable fields documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=search_fields_contact.htm&type=5) for Contact.

Based on the above, it is normal that SOSL does not return any results. I had a similar question in the past regarding SOSL on pick list fields on the Case Object [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/187004/sosl-query-field-limitations).

For the record, text(Encrypted) is not the same as text, hence, not queryable with SOSL.

When Using Shield Platform Encryption,

There are certain [considerations](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=security_pe_considerations_general.htm&type=0) when using SOSL and SOQL:

> Encrypted fields can’t be used with the following SOQL and SOSL
> clauses and functions:
>
> -Aggregate functions such as MAX(), MIN(), and COUNT_DISTINCT() WHERE clause
>
> -GROUP BY clause
>
> -ORDER BY clause

Comment: So there is no way to search on Text(encrypted) fcustom ields other than making that field type to Text? Will Text(encrypted) custom fields work with Shield Platform Encryption rather than

Comment: I just linked the doc and udpated my answer for that.